# cuda kernel convert integer to const char*

Tags: cuda, integer, char, constants

I am trying to convert an integer (32-bit) to a const char* from within `__global__ kernel()` function in CUDA and I cannot find a way to do it.

I cannot use string functions since it complains that I am trying to call a host function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a search online for itoa() implementations and make a device function with one that covers what you need.

You may want to rethink your design though. It could be that you're on the wrong track if you need to format strings on the GPU.

Comment: I rewrote to use integers instead of strings. Thanks !